# Extract data from nested json and store it different tables using postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a nested json file , I need to extract the data from the json file and store in different tables using postgresql.

Json File :

```
{
   "Master_Tables":[
      {
         "type":"Details",
         "features":[
            {
               "id":"0001",
               "type":"donut",
               "name":"Cake",
               "ppu":0.55,
               "batters":{
                  "type":"batter",
                  "features":[
                     {
                        "id":"1001",
                        "type":"Regular"
                     },
                     {
                        "id":"1002",
                        "type":"Chocolate"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               "toppings":{
                  "type":"toppings",
                  "features":[
                     {
                        "id":"5001",
                        "type":"None"
                     },
                     {
                        "id":"5002",
                        "type":"Glazed"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I tried without nesting, I am able to get. But with nesting I am not able to. I am getting all the records in a single table "Details"

Code I have tried without nesting:

```
select 
cast(json_array_elements(jsonData::json->'Master_Tables')::json -> 'type' as character varying) as table_name,
json_array_elements(jsonData::json->'Master_Tables')::json -> 'features' as data
from   "Incoming_json_Test"
```

Note: "Incoming_json_Test"  has the Json file in text format.

I expect the output as 3 different rows with table name and json_data in 2 different columns  in a table.

output format, I got without nesting is 
[O/P : without nesting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nrbZ.png)

Comment: Could you please **[edit]** your question and add the expected output? E.g. as a [formatted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) [ASCII table](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)? You can only return three different "tables" if you run three different SQL statements. A single query can't return more than one result

Comment: Apologies , The above query will give output as two different columns 1.Table_names : It has all the types ( like Details,Batters,Toppings) 2.Data : It has the JSON record for the types respectively. It is fine If I get the output in this format,later I can explode into different tables.

Comment: As @horse said please edit your question and add the expected output in tabular form.

Comment: I have given a screenshot of how output looks. Can you please have a look at this question . @a_horse_with_no_name ,